# python3 - os.path changes

Tags: python, python-3.3, os.path

I am using `python 3.3` in Windows 7.

The python file, `main.py` is in `D:\my proj\$MY\1`

I wrote the following code in that file:

```
import os

file_usage = "usage.txt"
p1 = os.getcwd()
print ("os.getcwd(): ", p1)

p5 = os.path.join(p1,"report")
print ("os.path.join: ", p5)

file = open(file_usage, "a")
file.write ("*****BLAH-BLAH*****")
file.close()
```

So, When I run my program in cmd, it gives me output like:

```
os.getcwd():  D:\my proj\$MY\1
os.path.join:  D:\my proj\$MY\1\report
```

Now, `usage.txt` file is generating in the directory where my `main.py` is located means inside the `1` folder.

But I have tried to modify the path that it should be saved in `report` folder as you can see the value of `os.path.join`.

So, I want to save the generated `usage.txt` in the `report` folder instead of `1`. 
What type of changes should I do? or what other modules do I need to use?

I'm a novice user. So, please try to tell me in-depth or send me links from where I can get more knowledge or examples related to this. I'm awaiting for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
open(os.path.join(p5, "usage.txt"), "w")
```

Since `p5` is the path to the report directory, this will open a `usage.txt` file inside that dir.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. It really works. And now I learned it too! Can you suggest me some links regarding python 3 from where I can learn about routine or general examples.

Comment: @magneto The documentation at http://docs.python.org/3/ is quite excellent. Check out [Google's Python class](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/) for exercises.

Comment: hmm, but why I feel like it's for a good programmer who can implement new things or can solve big errors. Because I have tried my best before asking anything here but I failed to understand most of the time. Sorry for late reply as I was out of town. Thanks again.

Comment: @magneto: Hmm, maybe [Learn Python the hard way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/) is more your cup of tea? Given that you seem to understand the basic concepts of programming but have some difficulty combining them, I think some intermediate tutorial with lots of practical exercises might suit you best.

Comment: yup, thanks but it seems on python 3. Anyway, I'm gonna try that. And how can I contact you personally? Can I have your email-id?

Comment: @magneto: I'm sorry, but I'm not going to tutor you for free. Just ask questions on SO if you run into trouble.